# Make a HTML with two columns of equal height and one of them scrollable

Tags: html, css, html-table, scrollable

I have a HTML-table consisting of one row and two columns (in other words, just two cells). The idea was to make the two columns (i.e. the two cells) have equal height, which - at least for me - turned out to be non-trivial if using floats or flexbox, hence why I resorted to a HTML-table.

The left cell (column) is filled with content dynamically, hence its height is not known beforehand. The right cell (column) is also filled dynamically (actually a Facebook feed), but its height should adapt to (i.e. always be equal to) the height of the left column. BUT this right column should ALSO be scrollable, meaning that the user can read all its content simply by using the column's own scrollbar.

So the point is to have the right column's height, as displayed on the screen, adapt to that of the left column, while also making the right column (but not the left column) scrollable.

By default, the right column has in fact equal height to the left column [apart from the annoying fact that the borders fall outside the cell, but let's leave that aside for now]. But the problems start once the right column's content becomes too big to fit. I could set "overflow-y: hidden;" for the content-div inside the right column, which would enforce equal height, but obviously that way the right column would not be scrollable (overflowing content would simply be cut off). [Set "overflow-y: hidden;" to the table cell itself, as opposed to the div contained in it, doesn't seem to do anything, which actually makes some sense, since it's the div and not the table-cell that overflows.]

Conversely, if I set "overflow-y: scroll;" I do get the desired scrollbar, but as it turns out, this does NOT enforce equal height: I get a useless scrollbar, while the column becomes so high as to be able to display all the content at once anyway.

Question is therefore: How do I get both equal height AND a scrollbar?

I've also experimented with "height: auto;" and "height: 100%; ", but neither  seem to help, as far as I could tell...

Here is a screen shot of the current situation:

[image]
<sub>(source: [test2468.nl](http://www.test2468.nl/wptest/Screenshot%20(3151).png))</sub>

You can see the right column's scrollbar (to the left of the *page* scrollbar), but you can also see that this column becomes higher than the left column.

The code as-is is quite simple:

```
<table>
<col width="60%">
<col width="38.7%">

<tr>

<td>
   [... Fill the left column/cell with dynamic content ]
</td>

<td id="fb-td" style="vertical-align: top;">
   <div id="fp2-rechts">
      <div class="faceb" id="fb-berichten2">
         <h3 id="fb-kop2">OP FACE-<br />BOOK</h3>
         <?php echo do_shortcode('[custom-facebook-feed id="168766623258787"  
         num=16]');   ?>
      </div>
   </div>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

As you see, there are two wrapper-div's inside the right table cell, which may be one to many, but this doesn't seem relevant here.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to use javascript for that. first find the max height of those to divs and assign that height both divs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution using CSS:

```css
table {
  position: relative;
}

td {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
}

.column2>div {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="column1">
      <div> a<br> a<br> a<br> </div>
    </td>
    <td class="column2">
      <div> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> b<br> </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try it out later today, will report back.

Comment: Yes, the demo works great, and, after cleaning up some of the CSS-mess I had created, I've got it working for myself now as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try like that

```
var maxHeight = 0;

$("div").each(function(){
  if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
});

$("div").height(maxHeight);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm experimenting right now, since I have to tweak the JavaScript code a bit to make it work. Right now I have achieved that the right column itself is basically as high as the left column (as seen from the height of the column's background image), but the *content* still overflows (i.e. continues beyond the column/cell itself). But as I said I'm going to experiment a bit further, and will report back later, just don't know exactly when...

Comment: you can assign (overflow: hidden) in css.

Comment: Well, I've got Arun's CSS solution working, so I'm going to accept that answer, also because it's pure CSS. I'll upvote your answer as well, however, because it's very relevant and I think it should work (it's just that my code is a bit messy and it'll cost too much time right now to clean everything up right now). Once I have a little time available, I'm going to look further into the Jasvascript solution as well, because I think I could learn from that as well. So hopefully I'll be able to report back on that within a few weeks.