# Two child tables side-by-side in one cell with same height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have two tables next to each other contained in a parent table's cell.
Is there any way (or trick one could use) to make both child tables fit the height of the parent cell with HTML and CSS?

So if a cell has more content than the other, they both would have the same height.

```html
<table cellpadding="0" border="1" cellspacing="0" style="border:none; border:thin solid black; width:600px;" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!--left table-->
      <table cellpadding="0" border="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:86px; height:100%; background-color:#808080; margin-left:0px;" align="left">
        <tr>
          <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-color:#808080; color:white;" align="center">
            Fit the height of the right side?
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <!--right table-->
      <table cellpadding="4" border="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:500px; height:100%;">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" height="42" valign="middle" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-color:#000000; padding-left:10px; color:white;">
            Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I suppose it's about backgrounds... simply set backgrounds to the parent TD  containers

Comment: If yo can not switch to a simple structure to use *CSS flexbox*, switch to javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34986296/4700922

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan good idea, but they are in the same td with two different colors.

Comment: @Pangloss ya.... I'd than split those into two separate TD and use backgrounds on those parents. That's what I mean

Comment: I was using one column (td) so that I could make the two child tables responsive for mobile devices.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to set a `table` height to `100%` unless the parent has a fixed height (probably not what you want).

Therefore, I'd split that parent `TD` into **two `TD`s** with the desired background colors

```html
<table cellpadding="0" border="1" cellspacing="0" style="border:none; border:1px solid black; width:600px;" align="center">
  <tr>

    <td style="vertical-align:top; background: #808080; color:white; width:86px;">
      <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
            Fit the height of the right side?
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>

    <td style="vertical-align:top; background: #000000; color:white; padding-left:10px;">
      <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="left">
            Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The reason I was floating the tables instead of putting them in two separate td's is to make them responsive for mobile devices.